# MVC 4 Data Annotations "Display" Attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am starting out with MVC 4 (Razor view engine). (I believe this may apply to MVC 3 and earlier as well.) I am wondering if there is any benefit to using the DisplayAttribute data annotation within a view versus just writing a string directly in the HTML. For example, if I had the following model:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string WildAndCrazyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

...would there be any benefit in annotating the property as:

```
    [Display(Name = "Wild and Crazy")]
    public string WildAndCrazyProperty { get; set; }
```

...and having my markup be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.WildAndCrazyProperty)</div>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.WildAndCrazyProperty)</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...versus not having the annotation, and doing:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Wild and Crazy</div>
        <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.WildAndCrazyProperty)</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason I haven't mentioned `Html.LabelFor` in this case is because the property's data is being displayed as static (i.e. non-editable) text on the page. The data will never be editable on this page, so there is no need for me to use `Html.TextBoxFor` within the second <div> and subsequently use the `Html.LabelFor` to properly associate a label with that text box.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If two different views are sharing the same model (for instance, maybe one is for mobile output and one is regular), it could be nice to have the string reside in a single place: as metadata on the ViewModel.

Additionally, if you had an inherited version of the model that necessitated a different display, it could be useful. For instance:

```cs
public class BaseViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Basic Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OtherViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Customized Inherited Name")]
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'll admit that that example is pretty contrived...

Those are the best arguments in favor of using the attribute that I can come up with. My personal opinion is that, for the most part, that sort of thing is best left to the markup.

Comment: And that's the way I am leaning. It seems that you would want something that is really more of a display-type-thing in the part of the code that does the actual displaying. Having to recompile the project just to change a heading or two seems unnecessary.

Comment: I wholly agree on the recompilation point. I feel like even if you had to use the model in multiple views, the pros of putting that data in an attribute do not outweigh the cons.

Comment: @kehrk - This example doesn't really work. It always pulls from the base class' definition, even if the property is abstract.

Comment: This also does not work for me. I even tried using an interface instead of a base class. I have a shared partial view where the business owner wants the Name to be different for just one instance and this solution seems like it should work, but doesn't.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the other answers, there is a big benefit to using the `DisplayAttribute` when you want to localize the fields.  You can lookup the name in a localization database using the DisplayAttribute and it will use whatever translation you wish.

Also, you can let MVC generate the templates for you by using `Html.EditorForModel()` and it will generate the correct label for you.

Ultimately, it's up to you.  But the MVC is very "Model-centric", which is why data attributes are applied to models, so that metadata exists in a single place.  It's not like it's a huge amount of extra typing you have to do.

Comment: In my current case, the app is just a test front-end for a WebAPI service. No localization is necessary; but I can see the benefit of such a behavior.

Comment: @KennethK. - there's lots of things that may not benefit you right now, but you may wish you'd done later.  Using a 3-tiered architecture may not benefit you now, but later... you'll be smacking your head.  The point is, use it or not.. it's your choice, but try not to imply that it's useless.

Comment: If I came across as implying the technique was useless, I certainly did not intend to. As I mentioned, the app is simply a facade to a web service. There is no chance of the application being used outside of this capacity. Since the app consists of exactly one view, I could not see the benefit. Now if I were designing a public-facing application with a global audience, yes, what you describe makes perfect sense. It is the size of this particular application which did not make clear why the attribute would be helpful.

Comment: "It's not like it's a huge amount of extra typing you have to do." It's not the typing that concerns me; it's the re-compilations if the text needs to change. Hypothetically speaking, what if you were in a shop which had "code-behind" guys and "UI" guys. If you had to make a change to a heading, would it not make more sense that the "UI" guy could (and should) do this?

Comment: The UI guy should know about ViewModels I guess. Also, if you are publishing using web deploy for example, the compilation shouldn't be a concern, since you are always deploying everything changed. When you deal with same object on different views, having it on the metadata is a life saver. Keeps consistency and if you need to change the name, in the view. you cannot know how many views you should change, while changing the metadata will save you from searching all around for that 'typo'

Comment: @Bart I agree with the web deploy and multiple views arguments, but I don't quite agree with not knowing how many views to change. A quick "Find All References" should point that out.

Comment: if he just write `<div>Wild and Crazy</div>`. there's no reference to look up for. Also, if you use data annontations, you don't need to encode special characters, mvc does this for you. but if your name is something like "niños" or "Wild > Crazy" you should write `ni&ntilde;os` or `Wild &gt; Crazy` in the html but not on data annotation.

Comment: If you use .resx files for localization you can just as well look the display text up in the view, and get rid of the hardcoded strings (ie. put them all in the same place)
`<div>@ThingResource.WildAndCrazy</div>`

Answer (score 10):

One of the benefits is you can use it in multiple views and have a consistent label text. It is also used by asp.net MVC scaffolding to generate the labels text and makes it easier to generate meaningful text

```
[Display(Name = "Wild and Crazy")]
public string WildAndCrazyProperty { get; set; }
```

"Wild and Crazy" shows up consistently wherever you use the property in your application.

Sometimes this is not flexible as you might want to change the text in some view. In that case, you will have to use custom markup like in your second example

Comment: In this case, I only have the one view, so perhaps that is why I could not perceive a benefit. Notwithstanding this benefit, it seems as though one might have a larger number of views reusing this same property before the consequence of recompilation would be outweighed by the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Also internationalization.

I fooled around with this some a while back.  Did this in my model:

```
[Display(Name = "XXX", ResourceType = typeof(Labels))]
```

I had a separate class library for all the resources, so I had Labels.resx, Labels.culture.resx, etc.

In there I had key = XXX, value = "meaningful string in that culture."