# Strongly Typed Model naming override

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a strongly typed model and it is grabbing the display name from the Database 'startAmount' which I am sure is what it is supposed to do, but how do I override this?

I want it to appear as 'Starting Amount'.

```
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IPACS_kpiHistory.startAmount)
<span class="field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IPACS_kpiHistory.startAmount)
</span>
</p>
```

I've looked at all of the method options and none of them seem to have a display text override option?

Comment: You may want to look into a Display Attribute on the model property. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735757/mvc-4-data-annotations-display-attribute

Comment: @Jarek thanks using data annotations helped me fix it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IPACS_kpiHistory.startAmount, "Starting Amount")
```

or by decorating your view model property with the `[Display]` attribute:

```
[Display(Name = "Starting Amount")]
public double startAmount { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have, it still shows the label name from the Database.  I comment on this answer did help me solve it however using Data Annotations.

Comment: So using the Display attribute worked for you? If so is there something else you would like to ask about this issue or can we consider it as resolved?

Comment: Actually I was able to get your previous method to work as well.  Was a goof on typing on my end.  Both methods you mentioned work.  Thank you.  Issue resolved.